# keeping activity properties onActivityResult

Tags: android

So I was working through a couple of Android Camera examples in which I

1. generate a file URI and set it to an class property
2. then calling the camera intent passing the File URI as a parameter
3. Handle `onActivityResult` and then display the saved image by loading the file from the file URI

My question is this: when handling the `OnActivityResult` the file URI property is null even though it is set before the camera intent is called.  I implemented the `onSaveInstanceState()` method and save the property to the bundle and then load it `onCreate` - which seems to have fixed the problem.  However, that means that my activity onCreate is being called before or after the `onActivityResult` and my properties are being reset.

Since the official Android examples don't implement `onSaveInstanceState` to hold on to that file uri variable, am I doing something wrong?  Is it normal for the `onCreate` to be called on the original activity when the `onActivityResult` is triggered from the camera intent?  Do I have to set the activity to be `singleTop` or something like that?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

In my case onCreate is not called when coming back from the camera and thus the file (or uri) is still good...

I can only think of two or three possibilities: you call finish manually somewhere by yourself, or the device/emulator you are testing on is low on memory and kills your activity, once the cam is in foreground or you have some task killer on your device that kills your activity...?

So, onCreate is not, at least not always, called and if you want to know, if you made something wrong, I guess it will be necessary to post your code.
(Although it seems like a good idea to handle the problem like you do, anyway)